# ConcurrentModificationException in unmodified ArrayList in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, concurrency, java-7

Had ConcurrentModificationException thrown in production, the list which throws is a vanilla java7 ArrayList, the List is not modified in the loop and is local to the method above - not being passed anywhere else.

The Exception was thrown consistently every time the api call was made until server restart - then it stopped.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:837)
    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.formatCookies(BestMatchSpec.java:175)
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:131)
```

Code is below but difficult to read outside of IDE, here's [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.1/org/apache/http/client/protocol/RequestAddCookies.java#174) where the call is made, see that matchedCookies is not passed out of the thread scope.

BestMatchSpec.formatCookies does not modify the cookies list:

```
public List<Header> formatCookies(final List<Cookie> cookies) {
    Args.notNull(cookies, "List of cookies");
    int version = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean isSetCookie2 = true;
    for (final Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        if (!(cookie instanceof SetCookie2)) {
            isSetCookie2 = false;
        }
        if (cookie.getVersion() < version) {
            version = cookie.getVersion();
        }
    }
```

The calling method RequestAddCookies.process constructs the list and doesn't make the list of cookies available to another thread.

```
public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context)
        throws HttpException, IOException {
...
    // Find cookies matching the given origin
    final List<Cookie> matchedCookies = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
    final Date now = new Date();
    for (final Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (!cookie.isExpired(now)) {
            if (cookieSpec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin)) {
                if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.log.debug("Cookie " + cookie + " match " + cookieOrigin);
                }
                matchedCookies.add(cookie);
            }
        } else {
            if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.log.debug("Cookie " + cookie + " expired");
            }
        }
    }
    // Generate Cookie request headers
    if (!matchedCookies.isEmpty()) {
        final List<Header> headers = cookieSpec.formatCookies(matchedCookies);
...
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @guido Is it relevant? The List is created in `RequestAddCookies.process` and the exception is thrown two stackframes down in `BestMatchSpec.formatCookies`.

Comment: nope you're right, actually notrelevant; the lines in the stacktrace do not tell much without knowning which version you are using too; did you check this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1173, in particular `-XX:-LoopUnswitching` and the last comment.

Comment: @guido Thankyou - it does look like we're using an affected version of java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @guido for pointing to this issue on apache. It is due to a bug with the JIT compiler fixed in java7u60. The code should not be able to produce the ConcurrentModificationException.

HttpClient report:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1173

Java bug:
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021898

Test to reproduce bug:
https://github.com/rholder/jvm-loop-unswitching-bug

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create a copy of the List `cookies` and iterate it .Definatly somewhere your list is being modified in any another thread.

If this is being used in a multithreaded environment , any thread could be accessing the list and modifying/iterating over the backing list with the iterator.

```
List<Cookie> newList = new ArrayList<Cookie>(cookies);
```

Comment: matchedCookies is a local variable - and it is not made available to another thread. It can be seen above that the only time the list is passed anywhere is in a predicate `notNull()`.
I've included the method header for process to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList`s iterator throws `ConcurrentModificationException` on calling `next()` method or when iterating over it using `for` loop (which is your case) when the same list was modified somewhere else.

To resolve your problem you have two possible ways to go:

1. Create a copy of your list as *amicngh* suggested; Although using `ArrayList` when it can be modified by several threads leads to data races - be aware of it;
2. Find out, which code modifies the list while you're trying to iterate over it. Due to the most probable semantics (cookies can be modified while you're formatting it in the method we're discussing) you may want to restrict list access somehow. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` may be your collection of choice as its iterators are thread-safe and doesn't throw `CME`.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that this List is made available to another thread. It is not so clear in SO but have a look in [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.1/org/apache/http/client/protocol/RequestAddCookies.java#174)